# redirect to another activities in android

Tags: android, sqlite

i made this login and register activities and after done register..user able to login and direct user to the main activities.how to do that?i know it is using intent but i dont know where to put it..here are the code after user click the login button.

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {

InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtUserName.getWindowToken(), 0);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtPassword.getWindowToken(), 0);
String username = txtUserName.getText().toString();
String password = txtPassword.getText().toString();
if (username.length() > 0 && password.length() > 0) {
try {

if (dbAdapter.Login(username, password)) {
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Successfully Logged In", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} 

else {
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
"Invalid username or password",
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

} catch (Exception e) {
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Some problem occurred",
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
} else {
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
"Username or Password is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
});

btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

Where show i put the code to direct user to main page and how..thanks..

Comment: when you want to show Main Screen to user on Login Success, on Login Invalid ?

Comment: meaning bro??i dont get it..well.i cant login..it said something about manifest.xml.. _T

Comment: You need to declare your second activity in your manifest. See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Comment: thanks bro..manage to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       if (dbAdapter.Login(username, password)) {
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Successfully Logged In", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       /***This is the code which redirect the user to another activity***/    
        Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this,OtherActivity.class);
         startActivity(in);
    }
```

Also Please mention your OtherActivity in your AndroidManifest.xml.So you may not get any force close messages

Comment: how to mention the activity in androidManifest.xml??i did explore but cant fid any...

Comment: Just open your AndroidManifest.xml find <application> tag inside it you find <activity> tag.At the end of this tag you may find </activity>.Just after this place this        
     <activity  android:name="com.example.project.OtherActivity">         </activity> .Just remember com.example.project is the package name and OtherActivity is the another activity.So just change this package name with your package name

Answer (score 0):

Redirect user on SUCCESSFULL LOGIN